# Lookup for values and return all matching rows

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, advanced-filter

Is there a way to look up for values(sheet2) in  sheet1 and copy all the matching rows to a new sheet (sheet3)?

```
Sheet1
Name    Hours   Group
Joy     12  AA
Allen   23  AA
Tom 34  AA
Amy 45  AX
Chris   6   AD
Allen   7   FG
Tom 8   GH
Joy     8   JK
Amy 23  UY
Jack    11  AA


Sheet 2 (col A):
Joy
Allen
Amy
Chris

Sheet 3 (expected o/p)
Joy     12  AA
Joy     8   JK
Allen   23  AA
Allen   7   FG
Amy 45  AX
Amy 23  UY
Chris   6   AD
```

Comment: Try the database functions DCOPY() etc

Comment: @SolarMike Just for my interest, can you provide more information about `DCOPY()` I couldn't find a database function in the [references](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Database-functions-reference-ad87e69b-fc20-4d3d-9d52-d7dc023f5c23) named `DCOPY()`.

Comment: Sorry DCOUNT() etc - excel can extract reports using the data as a database ie a restricted version of Access...

Comment: @SolarMike To get the result of Sheet3 what the OP wants, he needs to filter Sheet1 by the names of Sheet2. How would you do this with any of these database functions? I see barely a chance to achieve this without using filters, but you might proof me wrong.

Comment: I used those functions to extract relevant claims,sorry concerns, from warranty data (the text written by mechanics) searching for specific text terms or references... used macros when it was before vba and it would take over 12 hours to run - but that was when it was excel 3 or 4 and computer processors were 60MegaHertz not gigahertz. It was a suggestion or comment : not going to prove it is possible as I know I did achieve it... and I probably have a backup of the macros somewhere...

Answer (score 0):

#### What you try is actually filter sheet1 by the names of sheet2

Make use of *[Advanced Filters](https://support.microsoft.com/de-de/help/2720580/using-advanced-filters-in-excel-2010)* to achieve the result of sheet3.
But the restrictions are …

- it has to be done in the same sheet (Excel restricts it)
  so you need to copy the result to sheet3 after filtering it.
- you need to sort it by name before or after

The following image describes what parameters I used for advanced filter.
(Sorry for the german screenshot, I think you will figure it out.)

[image]

Note that you don't necessarily copy the result to another location, but can do a reversible filtering just in place of the original data. Which one to use depends on what you are going to do with that data later.

Also note, that the headlines (like 'Name') of the criteria range have to match the list range. The advanced filter uses them to find the column to filter on.